# Write .xlsx in R with double header

Tags: r, excel, data.table, xlsx

Is it possible to write a data.frame/data.table to a .xlsx with a double header? My data contains numeric, date and string columns. Please find a example below.

```
example <- data.frame(Number=c(1:5),
                      Date=as.Date('1999-10-31','1999-10-31','1999-10-31','1999-10-31','1999-10-31','1999-10-31'),
                      String=LETTERS[1:5])
```

Say, I would like to have a double header with Number being "One", Date being "Two" and String being "Three". But obviously I can't place them on row 1 since they 2nd column names are strings, and some columns are dates/numerics.

Any idea on this?

@Edit: example:

```
example <- data.frame(Number=c("One",as.character(1:5)),
                      Date=c("Two",'1999-10-31','1999-10-31','1999-10-31','1999-10-31','1999-10-31'),
                      String=c("Three",LETTERS[1:5]))

 Number       Date String
1    One        Two  Three
2      1 1999-10-31      A
3      2 1999-10-31      B
4      3 1999-10-31      C
5      4 1999-10-31      D
6      5 1999-10-31      E
```

But now obviously all columns are strings... And I need them as numerics and dates for specific fields. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for the desired output?

Comment: Exactly like that (row names and all)? If you insert `\n` between column name and One/Two/Three, you get a "wrapped" "two-line" name (e.g. `names(example) <- c("Number \n One", "Date \n Two", "String \n Three")`).

Comment: Thanks. But if I write it to xlsx, I need 1 row for each header. So that the first 2 rows in excel are the headers. With this solution they are in 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XLConnect` package for example. Here is a toy example using the `mtcars` data. You just need to proceed in two step: first write just the `colnames` (in `data.frame`) and write the data as usual starting at row 2.

```
library(XLConnect)
header <- data.frame(t(colnames(mtcars)))
header
##    X1  X2   X3 X4   X5 X6   X7 X8 X9  X10  X11
## 1 mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
writeWorksheetToFile(file = "/tmp/file.xlsx", data = header, sheet = "test",
                     startRow = 1, header = FALSE)

### Write the data as usual keeping the colnames
writeWorksheetToFile(file = "/tmp/file.xlsx", data = mtcars, sheet = "test",
                     startRow = 2)
```

Using the data you provided, you can something like this:

```
header <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("One", "Two", "Three")))
example <- data.frame(Number=c(1:5),
                      Date=as.Date('1999-10-31','1999-10-31',
                                   '1999-10-31','1999-10-31',
                                   '1999-10-31','1999-10-31'),
                      String=LETTERS[1:5])


writeWorksheetToFile(file = "/tmp/file2.xlsx", data = header, sheet = "test",
                     startRow = 1, header = FALSE)
writeWorksheetToFile(file = "/tmp/file2.xlsx", data = example, sheet = "test",
                     startRow = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "override" the `write.csv()` function like that

```
New_write.csv <- function(file,example)
{
    Header1 <- paste(names(example),collapse=",")
    Header2 <- paste(c("one","Two","Three"),collapse=",")
    writeLines(paste(Header1,Header2,sep="\n"),file)
    write.table(example, file, sep = ",", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE,row.names=F)
}
```

and then call it normally like that:

```
New_write.csv("example.csv",example)
```

Comment: Many thanks. But for specific purposes I need them in .xlsx format. Would that also be possible?

Comment: You can simply open .csv files with Excel and then save them as .xlsx

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I need to do this for many files. All this code will run in a loop where I repeat the code for hundreds of .txt files.